# Best way to compute the moving average of word vectors in JAX

Tags: python, jax

Let say I have a matrix `W` of shape `(n_words, model_dim)` where `n_words` is the number of words in a sentence and `model_dim` is the dimension of the space where the word vectors are represented. What is the fastest way to compute the moving average of these vectors ?

For example, with a window size of 2 (window length = 5), I could have something like this (which raises an error `TypeError: JAX 'Tracer' objects do not support item assignment`):

```py
from jax import random
import jax.numpy as jnp

# Fake word vectors (17 words vectors of dimension 32)
W = random.normal(random.PRNGKey(0), shape=(17, 32)) 

ws = 2          # window size
N = W.shape[0]  # number of words

new_W = jnp.zeros(W.shape)

for i in range(N):
    window = W[max(0, i-ws):min(N, i+ws+1)]
    n = window.shape[0]
    for j in range(n):
        new_W[i] += W[j] / n
```

I guess there is a faster solution with `jnp.convolve` but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you're trying to do a convolution, so `jnp.convolve` or similar would likely be a more performant approach.

That said, your example is a bit strange because `n` is never larger than 4, so you never access any but the first four elements of `W`. Also, you overwrite the previous value in each iteration of the inner loop, so each row of `new_W` just contained a scaled copy of one of the first four rows of `W`.

Changing your code to what I think you meant and using [index_update](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.ops.html#indexed-update-operators) to make it compatible with JAX's immutable arrays gives this:

```python
from jax import random
import jax.numpy as jnp

# Fake word vectors (17 words vectors of dimension 32)
W = random.normal(random.PRNGKey(0), shape=(17, 32)) 

ws = 2          # window size
N = W.shape[0]  # number of words

new_W = jnp.zeros(W.shape)

for i in range(N):
    window = W[max(0, i-ws):min(N, i+ws)]
    n = window.shape[0]
    for j in range(n):
      new_W = new_W.at[i].add(window[j] / n)
```

and here is the equivalent in terms of a much more efficient convolution:

```python
from jax.scipy.signal import convolve
kernel = jnp.ones((4, 1))
new_W_2 = convolve(W, kernel, mode='same') / convolve(jnp.ones_like(W), kernel, mode='same')

jnp.allclose(new_W, new_W_2)
# True
```

Comment: Thx for the corrections, I indeed should have to written  `new_W[i] += W[j] / n` and `window = W[max(0, i-ws):min(N, i+ws+1)]` !

Comment: Could you just detail what the 2 convolve do ? I think I get the shape (4, 1) for the ones (could also be (4, model_dim) no ?) but I dont get the denominator !

Comment: convolve(jnp.ones_like(W), kernel, mode='same') seems to scale properly the same way `n` scales in my code.

Comment: Also, after my last edit, the kernel in your code should be: `kernel = jnp.ones((5, 1))` such that it is centered on the middle word